# Registration form keep prompting error

Tags: php, jquery, html

The code on register page could work previously but after the `"function submitForm()"` in jquery. and i start to run the register form, it will keep flash with the icon on:

> echo "1"
>   [image]

here the php code on my register.php

```
<?php

$_POST = array(); //workaround for broken PHPstorm
parse_str(file_get_contents('php://input'), $_POST);

    require_once 'dbConn.php';

    $message='';

    if($_POST)
    {
        $user_nric = $_POST['nric'];
        $user_name = $_POST['name'];
        $user_email = $_POST['email'];
        $user_password = $_POST['password'];
        $user_gender = isset($_POST['gender']) ? $_POST['gender'] : '';
        $user_role = isset($_POST['role']) ? $_POST['role'] : '';

        $password = md5($user_password);

        try
        {
            $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM `user` WHERE nric=:nric");
            $stmt->execute(array(":nric"=>$user_nric));
            $count = $stmt->rowCount();

            if($count==0){

            $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO user(nric,name,email,password,gender,role) VALUES(:nric, :name, :email, :password, :gender, :role)");
            $stmt->bindParam(":nric",$user_nric);
            $stmt->bindParam(":name",$user_name);
            $stmt->bindParam(":email",$user_email);
            $stmt->bindParam(":gender",$user_gender);
            $stmt->bindParam(":role",$user_role);
            $stmt->bindParam(":password",$password);
            //$stmt->bindParam(":jdate",$joining_date);

                if($stmt->execute())
                {
                    echo "registered";
                }
                else
                {
                    echo "Query could not execute !";
                }

            }
            else{

                echo "1"; //  not available
            }

        }
        catch(PDOException $e){
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }
    }
```

?>

here the register jquery:

```
$('document').ready(function()
{
     /* validation */
     $("#register-form").validate({
      rules:
      {
            nric: {
            required: true,
            minlength: 9,
            maxlength: 9,
            nowhitespace: true
            },
            name: {
            required: true,
            minlength: 3,
            maxlength: 20,
            lettersonly: true
            },
            password: {
            required: true,
            minlength: 8,
            maxlength: 15
            },
            cpassword: {
            required: true,
            equalTo: '#password'
            },
            email: {
            required: true,
            email: true
            },
            gender: {
                required: function() {
                    return $('[name="gender"]:checked').length;
                }
            },
            role: {
                required: function() {
                    return $('[name="role"]:checked').length;
                }
            }
       },
       messages:
       {
            nric:{
                required: "Please enter the valid nric",
                minlength: "NRIC should be more than 9 characters",
                maxlength: "NRIC should be less than 9 characters",
                nowhitespace: "NRIC should not have any spaces"
            },
            name: {
                required: "please enter user name",
                minlength: "Name should be more than 3 character",
                maxlength: "Name should be less than 20 character",
                lettersonly: "Name should contain only letter"
            },
            password:{
                      required: "please provide a password",
                      minlength: "password at least have 8 characters"
                     },
            email: "please enter a valid email address",
            cpassword:{
                        required: "please retype your password",
                        equalTo: "password doesn't match !"
                      },
            gender: {
                required: "Select a gender"
            },
            role: {
                required: "Select a role"
            }
       },
       submitHandler: submitForm()
       });  
       /* validation */


       /* form submit */
       function submitForm()
       {        
                var data = $("#register-form").serialize();

                $.ajax({

                type : 'POST',
                url  : 'register.php',
                data : data,
                beforeSend: function()
                {   
                    $("#error").fadeOut();
                    $("#btn-submit").html('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-transfer"></span> &nbsp; sending ...');
                },
                success :  function(data)
                           {                        
                                if(data==1){

                                    $("#error").fadeIn(1000, function(){


                                            $("#error").html('<div class="alert alert-danger"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign"></span> &nbsp; Sorry nric already taken !</div>');

                                            $("#btn-submit").html('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> &nbsp; Create Account');

                                    });

                                }
                                else if(data=="registered")
                                {

                                    $("#btn-submit").html('<img src="../images/btn-ajax-loader.gif" /> &nbsp; Signing Up ...');
                                    setTimeout('$(".form-signin").fadeOut(500, function(){ $(".signin-form").load("register-success.php"); }); ',5000);

                                }
                                else{

                                    $("#error").fadeIn(1000, function(){

                        $("#error").html('<div class="alert alert-danger"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign"></span> &nbsp; '+data+' !</div>');

                                    $("#btn-submit").html('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> &nbsp; Create Account');

                                    });

                                }
                           }
                });
                return false;
        }
       /* form submit */

});
```

Comment: How can i stop the echo "1" from flashing?

Comment: Enable errors on your page and report back with them. Check the console as well.

Comment: i try debug but it won't return any error from it.

Comment: @jwalkerman What URL do you see in browser when this does not work?

Comment: http://localhost:63342/test/register.php?_ijt=8ioavs9n4umkgk8ag19sjmar8d

Answer (score 0):

if the nric is already exists in table user then echo 1 as the $count is not equals to zero. see the following code:

```
   if($count==0){

        $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO user(nric,name,email,password,gender,role) VALUES(:nric, :name, :email, :password, :gender, :role)");
        $stmt->bindParam(":nric",$user_nric);
        $stmt->bindParam(":name",$user_name);
        $stmt->bindParam(":email",$user_email);
        $stmt->bindParam(":gender",$user_gender);
        $stmt->bindParam(":role",$user_role);
        $stmt->bindParam(":password",$password);
        //$stmt->bindParam(":jdate",$joining_date);

            if($stmt->execute())
            {
                echo "registered";
            }
            else
            {
                echo "Query could not execute !";
            }

        }
        else{

            echo "1"; //  not available
        }
```

Comment: so anything that could prevent it from echo 1 ? even when i just refresh the form, it will keep flash the echo "1".

Comment: comment this  line `echo "1";`

Comment: use different function for javascript call to database

Answer (score 0):

remove echo "1" from here:

```
else{

        echo "1"; //  not available
```

and please reply what it does.

Comment: i remove echo "1", but it still flash with the icon.

Comment: Is this happening when registration page opens? or when you register someone?

Comment: it happens when i open the registration page.